# Python multiline assistance

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking to parse the output of `brctl show` via a python script, but I'm just not wrapping my head around multiline regex. If someone could provide a play by play I'd really appreciate it. I feel like I'm probably missing something trivial here.

Anyways, what I'm looking to do is take output like this:

```
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
backup      8000.101f7437d7bc   no      eth0
                                        vnet1
                                        vnet10
extra       8000.2c27d750e6a0   no      bond0.142
                                        vnet0
                                        vnet103
                                        vnet106
                                        vnet112
                                        vnet117
```

And create a dictionary, `interfaces`,  where the bridge name is the key and the value is a list of interfaces of that bridge, e.g.:

`interfaces[backup]=['eth0', 'vnet1','vnet10']`

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

output = '''bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
backup      8000.101f7437d7bc   no      eth0
                                        vnet1
                                        vnet10
extra       8000.2c27d750e6a0   no      bond0.142
                                        vnet0
                                        vnet103
                                        vnet106
                                        vnet112
                                        vnet117'''
interfaces = {}
for bridge_lines in re.findall(r'(?m)^\S.*\n(?: .*\n)+', output):
    # ^\S.*\n  matches first line that srats with non-space
    #     (backup ... or extra ...)
    # (?: .*\n)+  matches following lines that starts with space.

    bridge, _ = bridge_lines.split(None, 1)
    interfaces[bridge] = re.findall(r'(?m)\S+$', bridge_lines) # Get last fields

print(interfaces['backup'])
print(interfaces['extra'])
```

output:

```
['eth0', 'vnet1', 'vnet10']
['bond0.142', 'vnet0', 'vnet103', 'vnet106', 'vnet112']
```

Comment: what do the mi and m mean in the grouped regex's?

Comment: @Totem, `i` means `Ignore case`. I removed it because in the pattern there's no alphabet (`a-z`).

Comment: @Totem, `m` means `Multiline mode`. Without it, `^` matches only at the beginning of the input string, `$` matches only at the end of the string. While with `m` flag, `^` matches at the beginning of each line, `$` matches at the end of the each line.

Comment: @Totem, See [re.I](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.I), [re.M](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.M).

Comment: I had tried something similar to this, instead of `^[a-z]` I had `^.*` and I think one other difference (I'm not at my home desk at the moment). However, if I run the above, I get one dictionary key "bridge" that has a list of every interface in the `output`.

Comment: @TurboTurtle, I updated the code not to use `^[a-z]...` (7min. before you commented).  Did you specified `(?m)` ?

Comment: @falsetru I tried your modified code, however now I do not get any results (i.e. empty dictionary)

Comment: @TurboTurtle, It works both in Python 2.x, Python 3.x. See http://asciinema.org/a/6976

Comment: @TurboTurtle, Maybe the output of the `brctl show` is different from the output posted in the question ?

Comment: @falsetru Hmm. The only difference I have is that instead of shoving the text into the `output` variable manually, I am using a text file that contains the output of `brctl show`. 

Basically I have that file  opened, then set a `bridge_ouput` variable = brctl_file.read() and fead `bridge_output` to the regex, in place of `output`.

Comment: @TurboTurtle, Please upload the file somehwere and let me knowo the url.